# How to enable a dropdown to have default value instead of selected

Tags: jquery, html, postback

I have a shopping website where i have a State Dropdown which is a usercontrol auto generated by a Third Party Shopping module. Since i do not have access to the source code i have to rely on my jQuery Skills to make any changes to the UI.

Now i add a option to the dropdown by using the following script.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args){
    jQuery("select[id$='BillingSubdivisionDropDownList']").prepend("<option value=''  selected='selected'>Select County/State</option>");
}
```

This adds the "Select County/State" option to the top of the list. The problem that i have is this control does an autopostback when i change the value and when it does that the selected option in that dropdown changes to my custom "Select County/State". How do i stop this from happening? Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: have you tried `event.stoppropagation()`?

Comment: @HamedAliKhan This is not an event handler.

Comment: use a hidden field to check on dropdown selction postback set some flag in hidden field and check if its set then don't prepend this option